# can't sum up integers in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I'm a newbie, with a really big headache caused by my inexperience in programming. Self-taught, without any support. Really need your help, that is just my second programming project please be patient. 
The problem is in creating new elements, where my summing up function fails. For now I've just created one to sum up hours (minutes and seconds doesn't work, but eventually will). With just one element ('plane') on the page it runs correctly.
). I appreciate any help and advice! Thank you in advance.
Below I link to my codepen:
http://codepen.io/annadrybulska/pen/LxVNYJ

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sum = 0;
$('#plane').on( 'click', '.plus-btn', function(){

    var hours = Number($(this).parent().find('input[name="hours"]').val()); //.time-timer
    sum += hours;

    var y = $(this).parentsUntil('.plane').siblings().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"}).find('.plane-hours').text(sum);

})

});
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, @Deep I'm trying to sum up hours and pass then to the element on the right side, every time user click on the green plus button individually for each plane witch was created above by inserting it's name. A'm I explaining it clear? Sorry if not.

Comment: ok, right now the code pen display the number of hours entered by user on the right section on click of the .plus-btn. You are trying to sum hours but there is only one element input[name="hours"]. What is purpose of sum ?

Comment: The idea is to be able to create some planes. In real life, those plane are RC models. After creating one of them you can enter the time that actually that plane have flown  in real life. After another flight the user will be able to enter a new time, and that time will be summed up an passed to the counter on the right. I'm wishing to be able to clear the timer(on  the left - the one you actually can insert some input) after user clicks the sum button....

Comment: Something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygbKmd ??

Comment: ohh @Deep I really appreciate it!!!!, you re awesome!! can you give me a hint what was wrong with the function? why you got rid of the "$(document).ready(function() " ? you are great @Deep!

Answer (score 0):

Okk, I made the following changes to your existing code.

1: Instead of initializing the sum with a 0 value every time, i have initialize it with the current value of the span.plane-hours  of the row where .plus-btn button is clicked

2: Capture the value entered by the user in the input[name="hours"] element in a variable called hours.

3: Reset the value of input[name="hours"]

4: Add the value of hours with the sum variable.

5: Update the text ot span.plane-hours  with this calculated value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#plane').on( 'click', '.plus-btn', function(){

var sum = Number($(this).parentsUntil('.plane').siblings().find('.plane-hours').text());
 var hours = Number($(this).parent().find('input[name="hours"]').val()); //.time-timer

$(this).parent().find('input[name="hours"]').val("00")

sum += hours;

$(this).parentsUntil('.plane').siblings().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"}).find('.plane-hours').text(sum);

})
});
```

Code Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjmQGb

P.S You can keep the document.ready as logic is not affected by this.